# Amazon AWS EC2 - Getting a .cer file instead of .pem

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

When i downloaded my private key file from Security Credentials, I got a .cer file instead of a .pem. I tried to ssh to my ec2 instance using that but i am constantly getting:

Bad passphrase, try again for pk-xxxxxxxxxxx

Is it because i have a .cer file or because i need a pass phrase? I do not know what is a passphrase. I would really appreciate if i can be helped soon. I think i am confusing the the .cer files i get from X.509 with the file i need for ssh. But the problem is i never get .pem files, only .cer file

Comment: What are using to SSH into your instance? If you are using Putty, you will need to convert that to PPK format using something like puttygen

Comment: im using command line ssh as i am using mac os x. do i need to convert my .cer to a .pem ??

Comment: The cer file should work just fine if you are using OSX terminal. I don't think you will need to convert the file to pem. Just try renaming the file. Also, make sure the file permissions are right on the file.  chmod 400 file.pem

Answer (score 49):

I have just started working on the Amazon AWS platform and came across this question.

Not sure if you managed to resolve your issue - however, here is a AWS forum thread that talks of a related issue and the solution:

[ssh error: "Enter passphrase for key 'id_rsa-gsg-keypair'"](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=23359)

To summarize the thread - the problem seems to be with the permissions on the .cer file that was downloaded.

Another thing about the **.cer** file - A **.cer** file is essentially confirmant with the PEM format and hence there should be no problem using the **.cer** file just like you would use a **.PEM** file.

I downloaded my **.cer** file and was able to connect to my Amazon Linux instance using it after having the correct permissions (**chmod 400 mykey.cer**) and then using it in the **ssh** command as below:

```
ssh -i mykey.cer ec2-user@public-dns-of-my-amazon-instance
```

Probably the connecting user varies for other linux instances. More information [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html)

Comment: Better still, add everything into an SSH config file: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/

Comment: It's nice to know that the two extensions are compatible, but it doesn't help when AWS says we have to download the `.pem` file but gives us the `.cer` file instead. :-|

Comment: Small note: The user to be used is indeed called `ec2-user` as of 2023 by default which is something that wasn't obvious to me at first.

Answer (score 14):

Try downloading the file in a different browser I had similar trouble when I was downloading ec2 instance using Brave Browser but didn't have any trouble when I used safari.

chmod 400 mykey.pem

ssh -i mykey.pem bitnami@x.x.x.x

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem myself. The "Connect" feature on the EC2 instance stated that it was a `.pem` file but the actual download was `.cer`

I ran `chmod 400 FILENNAME.cer` but still could not log in. Then I inspected the ssh link and noticed that it was also a `.pem` file. I switched the `.pem` to `.cer` and it worked!

Comment: Rename the `.cer` extension to `.pem` and it works well.

Comment: @pirateofebay where is the ssh link? I am beginner, trying to find .pem file but have .cer file

Answer (score 3):

Just rename the file from .cert to .pem and it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to everyone else's replies, this is just Amazon documentation being weird.

They provide a download of .cer files, but their 'helpful' connection docs/helper references .pem

1. navigate to where you downloaded the .cer ( ie. `cd Desktop`)
2. `chmod 400 name_of_cer_file_here.cer`
3. `ssh -i "name_of_cer_file_here.cer" your_user_here@ec2-123-456.region.compute.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue which gave me a "no such file or directory" error message because my Ec2 ssh key appeared with a `.cer` extension in my directory instead of a `.pem`.

1. I changed the extension to `.pem`
2. Reran `chmod` .... command to make the key private in my terminal, iTerm.
3. Ran `ls -al key-name` without the extension in the terminal to confirm its presence in the directory.
4. Then reran the `ssh` ..... command all over again

It works!