# AWS key pair .pem saving as .cer from MacOs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I made a new key pair as .pem but when i look up my finder it is downloaded as .cer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzHpd.png)
How can I save it as .pem file

Comment: How are you creating the keypair?

Answer (score 0):

They can usually be used interchangeably for key pairs, as your `.cer` file likely contains pem encoded data. See if the solutions here work for you - [Amazon AWS EC2 - Getting a .cer file instead of .pem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225112/amazon-aws-ec2-getting-a-cer-file-instead-of-pem)

For more context - https://www.ssl.com/guide/pem-der-crt-and-cer-x-509-encodings-and-conversions/